# oncomplete can't execute my javascript function

Tags: javascript, tags

```
     <a4j:commandButton id="save" value="save"

             action="#{objectHome.persist()}"
            rendered="#{!objectHome.managed}" 
            disabled="#{!objectHome.wired}"



          oncomplete= "myfunction(#{objectHome.instance.idd})">
              </a4j:commandButton>

            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(x)
{ 

window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/projet/doc.seam?ObjectIdd="+x+" "); 
}



/////and in my file.page.xml 


<navigation from-action="#{objectHome.persist()}">
      <rule if-outcome="persisted">
         <end-conversation/>
         <redirect view-id="/filepdf.xhtml"/>
      </rule>
   </navigation>
```

The problem is when I click in the save button the redirection in `filepdf.xml` is done successfully but the `oncomplete` can't call `myfunction` (it's a redirection in the same page).

Comment: Why don't you just call your oncomplete function in a onload event of the new page?

Comment: normalement l action doit etre executer avant la fonction d oncomplete..

Comment: ah ok sorry :),I'm debutante in javascript and I can not use onload well, what I want to know is where is the problem exactly for my function does not run, normally with onComplete  the action can be run before onclick so we can get the value of parameter of the javascript function